# MS WOPI: How to remove edit option in iframe

Tags: ms-wopi

I am using MS Wopi when the file is open for the view so how to remove the edit option as seen in the image.[image]

Comment: What have you tried? How did it work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WOPI how to remove edit icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66635933/wopi-how-to-remove-edit-icon)

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like this,

You can have Edit and View separate in the View. So I have passed some parameters with the session context in WOPI action URL to identify what is the operation.

Ex:
`https://{_baseUrl}/wopi/files/{combinedDocumentId}?sc=<your value>&wopisrc={wopiHostUrl}`

By checking that you can get value inside the Session Context with,

`Request.Headers["X-WOPI-SessionContext"]`

Keep in mind this value comes with Base64 encoded.

Then you need to decode it and pass it to the GetFileInformation function.

With that, you can set,

`ReadOnly = true`

`UserCanWrite = false`

for disabling edit on that iframe.