# WOPI how to remove edit icon

Tags: ms-wopi

When a user opens a file for viewing then the edit icon is available. You can see the following screen:
[image: WOPI View Screen].

When I change `UserCanWrite` to `false` then this icon is removed and the user does not have permissions to edit the file. If I change `UserCanWrite` back to `true` then the editing process is working fine but it again displays this edit icon when viewing the file.

Is it possible to remove this edit icon?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`WebEditingDisabled`](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/files/CheckFileInfo.html#term-webeditingdisabled). According to the docs:

> A Boolean value that indicates that the WOPI client must not allow the user to edit the file. Note that this does not mean that the user doesn't have rights to edit the file. Hosts should use the UserCanWrite property for that purpose.